# High credit usage - information_schema.query_history

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an optimized way of identifying long running queries in Snowflake? What I noticed is querying `information_schema.query_history` with or without providing values for parameters makes no difference in the cost incurred.

*Background*:
We have an AWS lambda that runs periodically to look for any long running queries by leveraging `information_schema.query_history`. But every execution would cost 0.18 credit regardless of the value you provide to parameters `end_time_range_start`,etc to restrict the data you get back.

So, both these queries would incur the same cost.

```
table(
      information_schema.query_history
      (
        end_time_range_start=> dateadd('minutes',-5,current_timestamp()),
        result_limit=>100
      )
     )


table(information_schema.query_history(result_limit=>100))
```

Note: We are already using `STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` to set a limit on the query duration at the warehouse level. Also, we have resource monitors in place to limit the credits used but we need a more granular solution to alert us if anyone runs a long running query.

Comment: Are you looking for queries that are ACTIVELY taking a long time to execute, or are you looking for a historical view?

Comment: Want to see long running queries in real time

Answer (score 0):

You can query SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY directly to get more control over the queries that are returned to you.  This contains 1 year worth of data, but has up to a 45 minute delay in the data being shown there.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

On the costs side of things, if you are leveraging the warehouse that is most frequently in use for your query to execute on, then it really isn't costing you any additional credits.  I would look into switching to that warehouse, if you can.

Comment: Thanks Mike!. We don't have any active warehouse running all the time; and we don't want to use stale data.So, I decided to create a separate warehouse (X-small) with a auto-suspend value of 1 min. With this setup, we incur only 0.017 credit for every run.

Comment: @patks You might want to just consider adding an ALTER WAREHOUSE SUSPEND statement to your Lambda job.  Then, you're not waiting the minute for it to shutdown.  In this way, you'd only be charged for that first minute, instead of a minute and some change.  How often is the Lambda function scheduled to run?

Comment: Lambda runs every half hour. I enabled AUTO-SUSPEND to 30 seconds. Query takes 1-5 seconds. But because Snowflake charges for the entire minute, we get charged only 0.017 per execution for the X-Small warehouse

Answer (score 0):

Query pruning accessing the view [`SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html)
seems to be effective only when filtering on `START_TIME`, not `END_TIME`.

I had to change my "save the query history on a daily basis" procedure because of this,
speeding up execution times > 4x.

Comment: SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY  is not an option for us since there is a 45 min delay

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is to run `SHOW WAREHOUSES` first. This doesn't use a warehouse and allows you to see if any warehouses are running. If none are running, then you surely don't have a long running query*, and you can stop here. If any are running, then you can opportunistically execute your query_history query on that warehouse without incurring the 1 minute minimum penalty.

With this you should be able to make this run at almost zero extra cost.

*an exception could be if you have a query that takes a long time compiling - if you're worried about that, then this approach won't work.